# Recompiling older version of project from Visual Sourcesafe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-sourcesafe

I have a couple of questions regarding Visual Sourcesafe. I have a .NET c# project I want to get a copy of and compile. I have the date when it was uploaded and that is the version I need to recompile. I had never used sourcesafe before so my two rookie questions are these:

1. Can I extract a full project from that specific day?
2. Will that mess up the current version of that same project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the files in a project on a specific date you have to use the command line, like this:

```
ss Get "$/YourProjectName" -R -Vd19-09-2013;3:20p
```

Note: `-R` is recursive get and `-Vd` gets a version at a specific date. Also take note of the SourceSafe date format.

Read [Get (Command Line)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/661w6e3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Luis Garcia - feel free to up-vote this answer. :-)